# Number of samples needed for the empirical (discrete) distribution to converge to the underlying distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling

My apologies if this is something standard in statistics. 
My problem is as follows:
I have a discrete population distribution with finite support and I would like to use observed samples to obtain the empirical distribution function. How can I determine the required number of samples, $n$, such that the empirical distribution function, $\hat{p}_n$, approximates the population distribution function, $\hat{p}$, with some certainty?

i.e. what is the minimum $n$ such that $Pr\{|\hat{p}_n - p| \leq \epsilon \} \geq 1 - \delta$ for some $\delta$, e.g. 0.05? In my case, I do not have a specific parametric form of the distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, what you want is the [Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality).

It it stated in the form:

$P(\text{sup}_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|F_n(x)- F(x)|>  \epsilon)\leq 2 \exp(-2n\epsilon^2)$.

This seems to be more or less what you want, even though your difference between $p_n$ and $p$ is not really defined. I suspect you mean the supremum.

There probably is some version specifically for your case.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this, I guess that the supremum should be a sufficient measure, I am not a statistician.